# C# Packing multiple signed integers into a single 64-bit value

Tags: c#, 64-bit

I need to pack and unpack several values to/from a single 64-bit value. I have 3 signed integers (x,y,z). I would like to pack them into a single 64-bit value (signed or unsigned doesn't matter to me) using 24, 16, and 24 bits for the values respectively. Here are my requirements:

1) I can ensure ahead of times that the values being stored do not exceed the limits of the number of bits I am using to store them into the 64-bit value, so no additional checks need to be made.

2) The initial values are signed, so I'm thinking some kind of bit magic may need to be done in order to ensure that nothing is lost.

3) This conversion is going to take place a LOT, so it needs to be fast. I know in C++ this can pretty easily be done by storing the values in a struct that specifies the integer length, and then establishing a pointer that just points to the first value that can be used for the 64-bit value. With this method, there really isn't any math that needs done, everything is just memory read or right. As far as I can tell, this can't be done quite so simply in C#, but C# is what I have to work with for this project.

4) I don't really care if the 64-bit value is signed or unsigned, so long as I can go both ways with the operation and recover the initial values, and whatever type is used can be used for a Dictionary key.

Comment: That's just a requirements dump, not a question. Have you tried a solution using bitwise operations, and if so, what issues did you have with it?

Comment: So create a `struct` that holds a `long` value. We do something very similar in Noda Time. (https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/YearMonthDayCalendar.cs) What exactly are you trying to ask for in this question?

Comment: Maybe using `union` and `struct` as one of members (`uint64` for the other).

Comment: It is very clear what OP is trying to ask. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> With this method, there really isn't any math that needs done, everything is just memory read or write.

Not really, the math is done when you set partial integers into bitfields, so there's quite a bit of math going on.

> As far as I can tell, this can't be done quite so simply in C#, but C# is what I have to work with for this project.

Correct, in C# you would need to write code that combines bits into a `long` manually. Assuming that you have taken care of range checking, this is relatively straightforward:

```
static long Pack(long a24, long b16, long c24) {
    // a24 can go with no masking, because its MSB becomes
    // the MSB of the 64-bit number. The other two numbers
    // need to be truncated to deal with 1s in the upper bits of negatives.
    return a24<<40 | (b16&0xffffL)<<24 | (c24&0xffffffL);
}
static void Unpack(long packed, out int a24, out int b16, out int c24) {
    a24 = (int)(packed >> 40); // Sign extension is done in the long
    b16 = ((int)(packed >> 8)) >> 16; // Sign extension is done in the int
    c24 = ((int)(packed << 8)) >> 8;  // Sign extension is done in the int
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/WBIftR)

Comment: another nice answer...

Comment: Agreed; that's some very slick bit fiddling to make the narrowing cast function as the mask (especially `c24`). Personally I prefer the "obviousness" of explicit masks, but I suspect they'll perform very similarly. This approach is *especially* nice for signed data, though; like it.

Comment: Wow, both this and Marc Gravell's answer are great, however, since this one directly addresses the need for signed values, I'm going to accept it. I appreciate the help with this.

Answer (score 10):

Masks and shifts are probably your best option. You can create explicit layout structs in C#, but there's no 24-bit primitive, so you'd be tripping over yourself and have to mask *anyway*. As soon as you're shifting, it is usually best to work unsigned (especially when right-shifting), so:

```
ulong val = ((((ulong)x) & 0xFFFFFF) << 40) // 24 bits of x, left-shifted by 40
          | ((((ulong)y) & 0xFFFF) << 24) // 16 bits of y, left-shifted by 24
          | (((ulong)z) & 0xFFFFFF); // 24 bits of z, no left-shift
```

and to reverse that (assuming that we want `uint` values):

```
uint a = (uint)((val >> 40) & 0xFFFFFF),
     b = (uint)((val >> 24) & 0xFFFF),
     c = (uint)(val & 0xFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 5):

These values are byte-aligned inside the long, you'll want to take advantage of Intel/AMD processors being able to directly access them to make the code as fast as possible.  The killer requirement is the 24 bit size, the processor can only directly read/write 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits.

That is a problem in C++ as well, you'd have to use bit-fields.  C# does not support them, you'll have to write the code that the C++ compiler emits automatically.  Like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MyPackedLong {
    [FieldOffset(0)] uint item1;    // 24-bit field
    [FieldOffset(3)] uint item2;    // 24-bit field
    [FieldOffset(6)] ushort item3;  // 16-bit field

    public uint Item1 {
        get { return item1 & 0xffffff; }
        set { item1 = (item1 & 0xff000000) | value; }
    }
    public uint Item2 {
        get { return item2 & 0xffffff; }
        set { item2 = (item2 & 0xff000000) | value; }
    }
    public ushort Item3 {
        get { return item3; }
        set { item3 = value; }
    }
}
```

Some trickorama here, note how `item2` has an intentional offset of 3 so that no shift is necessary.  I ordered the fields so their access is optimal, putting the 16-bit value either first or last is best.  Not thoroughly tested, ought to be in the ballpark.  Be careful in threaded code, the writes are not atomic.